# `\includegraphics` side-by-side and filling text-width

Tags: graphics

Instead of the figure environment I am trying to use the `\includegraphics` command to add pictures to an appendix.

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=\linewidth]{../pics/results_t/props_T_i_a}
\end{center}
```

Idea [from here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1887) for adding a picture without the float feature.

**Two questions:**

1. How do I add two images side-by-side? This is something I would usually do with `subfigure` inside the figure environment.
2. Instead of setting the scaling to a set number, I would like to set the text line width as is the usual method for figures. the `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` commands as shown in the code give errors, so how can I use them properly?

Comment: `scale` want a numeric value, i.e. i relative number, not an absolute number. And simply put two `includegraphics`-commands within the center invironment.

Comment: Don't use scale, use Width=0.5\linewidth for each image and make sure there is no space between the two images. You can still use the figure environment, even if you omit the caption and reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An appendix often consists of many many figures, or only figures. Having them float around will do no good. Hence, put the graphics inside the text directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You can also define a new environment, possibly together with package `capt-of`.

[image: steeveAppendixFigure2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\newenvironment{appendixfig}{\addvspace{5ex}\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
}{%
\end{minipage}\par\addvspace{4ex}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{appendixfig}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
\end{appendixfig}
\begin{appendixfig}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \captionof{figure}{Two nice figures}
\end{appendixfig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the lower example. Made my result much better. Can a centering be put on the `appendixfig` environments so small pictures would be centered?

Comment: @Steeven Yeah, sure `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering`